# Tableau - Filter Results Based on Name

Tags: filter, tableau-api, data-analysis

I have a view with calibration data where hosts create a calibration session, provide scores, then open up the sessions for others to join and score and see how they compare.
Example of my data:

| Date | SessionID | Participant Type | Name | Score | *New Calculated Field* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-04-01 | 250 | Host | John Smith | A | *John Smith* |
| 2022-04-02 | 250 | Participant | Jane Doe | A | *John Smith* |
| 2022-04-04 | 250 | Participant | Ed Jones | B | *John Smith* |

I'm trying to create a field in Tableau where users can filter to/select the Host's name and see the results of all participants for that SessionID. In the example above, they would select "John Smith" and see the data for John Smith, Jane Doe, and Ed Jones.

Based on research, I believe I need to use FIXED, but am not sure how to write that calculation. Any assistance would be appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: @thecoolmacdude honestly everything I've tried hasn't even come close to what I need and I didn't save my attempts unfortunately